# Creating directory in uploads: mkdir vs wp_mkdir_p

Tags: directory

```
$file_dir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/foo/';
```

Why would  you need to use wp_mkdir_p when mkdir can do its job here?

```
if(!file_exists($file_dir))wp_mkdir_p($file_dir);
```

or

```
if(!file_exists($file_dir))mkdir($file_dir);
```

Comment: You can look at [`wp_mkdir_p` in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1573) to see what it does.

Answer (score 4):

There is not much a difference but, for `wp_mkdir_p()` we can only pass the full path to attempt to create a folder. It is recursive directory creation function which check for the `file_exists()` or not. And moreover we don't need to pass the folder permission because it checks for the parent directory permission and sets the folder permission as that of the parent directory.

But, with `mkdir()` we need to check for the `file_exists()` function before creating a directory and the directory permission will be set as the permission defined by the WordPress itself during the setup.